# asp.net content page can't access html files in masterpage

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

i have created default web form and and connected to the html files in masterpage

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">

    </asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent1" Runat="Server">
    <div id="box">
                <p class="test">

                    <a target="_blank" href="webpage/rome/rome.aspx">
                        <img src="Images/rome.jpg" alt="">
                    </a>
                </p>

                <p>
                    In this series we are going to cover Ancient Rome.  We will cover the Roman Republic as well as the Roman Empire. Please click on the image above to load the series on Rome.
                </p>
            </div>
</asp:Content>
```

this works well.
 then created another .aspx content pages and althouth i can access masterpage by default other don't have the html files in the masterpage.
[here the circle area don't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8XFE.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your master page file `MasterPage.master` check that you have following element:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="MainContent1"><asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

So idea here is that ContentPlaceHolderID attribute value on child page must match the id on master page

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent1" Runat="Server">
```